Question about regression
Let's assume that I have large samples of data for the price and quantity of a product. I regress this data and I find that the correlation is one. Since the residuals in a linear regression are 0 when correlation is one, can I now conclude that there is a causal effect? If not, what else do I need to conclude there is a causal effect?

I will point you to the necessary xkcd (https://xkcd.com/552/), and the wiki page dealing with it (https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/552:_Correlation). YOu may find it informational.

Your primary question is addressed at Under what conditions does correlation imply causation?
But in addition to that: if I find a correlation of exactly 1, I would usually assume that

something has gone wrong in my code, or
one of the variables is a linear transformation of the other (and so calculating a correlation coefficient would be meaningless).


Fundamentally, correlation is not causation. From a fundamental philosophical perspective, you can never really prove causality. Practically this means that that there is always a chance that the pattern you observe is due to random chance, or that there is a separate, unobserved cause generating both variables.
Now, you are confusing correlation and regression a bit, but practically, if you perform this regression, you could say based on past information that the price is predictable from information about quantity. You may have good reason to infer causality, but proving causality is outside the realm of statistics.
